# Pre-Roman structures in Northern Europe

Tags: ancient-history

Do we have any surviving remnants or written accounts of pre-Roman buildings in Northern Europe?

Comment: Besides Stonehenge and the myriad other "henges"?

Comment: What do you mean by remnants? Remaining buildings or remains of buildings? There are archaeological sites with the foundations of pre-Roman buildings.

Answer (score 4):

**Celtic Culture and oppidum maps of northern europe and the la tene & Hallstad migrations**
[image]

[image]

**heat map of the megalithic cultures of europe**

[image]

**Map of megalithic sites in england and northern europe**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There were many hillforts in Northern Europe built by the Celtics, some of which remain today, such as Solsbury Hill. Numerous Viking ring fortresses also exist, including Aggersborg.

Of course, there is also Stonehenge in Salisbury, and in Ireland Newgrange and the fortress Dun Aonghasa. Hope this helps.